# Configure WSO2 ESB for corporate proxy so it can access external URIs

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb

How do I configure `WSO2ESB` such that I can proxy a service that I currently have hosted on Windows Azure?

On my local development machine I have an instance of WSO2ESB, I can use this to proxy WCF services also on my local development machine, but now I need to take this proof of concept work further and show how WSO2ESB could be used to proxy for WCF services hosted externally, in this instance on Windows Azure.

I have tried to add a new Proxy Service for my Azure service selecting `Specify source URL` for the Publishing WSDL and then entering the `.svc` address for my Azure service, but when I Test URI (which takes about a minute) it returns

> Invalid WSDL URI (Unable to establish a connection)

I believe this to be caused by our corporate proxy and my machine needing to supply basic information in order to punch a hole out but I cannot see how / where to do this.

I am using **WSO2ESB 4.5.1** and my Proxy Service source is:

```
<proxy xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse" name="Azure" 
       transports="https,http" 
       statistics="disable" trace="disable" startOnLoad="true">
  <target>
    <outSequence>
      <send/>
    </outSequence>
    <endpoint>
      <address uri="http://myazureservice.cloudapp.net/Service.svc"/>
    </endpoint>
 </target>
 <description></description>
</proxy>
```

**Update**
I have also tried importing the WSDL the service generates by copying it to the clipboard and pasting it into WSO2 but this is rejected.

Answer (score 0):

You can download the wsdl to your local filesystem with the extension of *.wsdl, and provide its link to the  "publishWSDL" option